# How to embed mercury in rails forms

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to use the Mercury editor in existing rails forms which will contain Mercury fields and fields that are not handled by Mercury.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without changing anything except the _form partial.

Here is the sample form:

https://gist.github.com/railscash/5697414

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore. Can you please help me with the code.